# duplicate amount column for payment transaction design

Tags: database, database-design

There are few payment methods: credit/debit card, cash, bitcoin

This is my payment transaction table:

```
Transaction:
| ID | AMOUNT  | METHOD |
| 1  |   80    | credit |
| 2  |  100    | cash   |

Transaction_credit:
| ID | AMOUNT  | TYPE     | TRANSACTION_ID |
| 1  |   80    | sale     | 1              |
| 2  |  -80    | reversal | 1              |

Transaction_cash:
| ID | AMOUNT  | TYPE     | TRANSACTION_ID |
| 2  |  100    | payment  | 2              |
| 2  | -100    | refund   | 2              |
```

Do you think it is a good idea to have amount in card, cash, and bitcoin sub table?

How can I solve the duplicate amount in sub table?

Comment: This looks like a bad idea in the making.  I'd much rather have a single table for all transactions, along with one or more columns to distinguish cash from cards from cryptos.

Comment: yes, it does look messy, but credit card has many column, which i am not listed here, so it is cleaner to have multiple table, because we still have many payment type to support.

Comment: As you wish, but I vote for a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your database design needs some improvements.

**Firstly**: Transaction Entity (Table) in Accounting Systems holds **all** money transactions. If your sales are reversal, you should make a new Transaction row too. Also, if your Payment refunded, you should make a new Transaction row too.

**Secondly**: Details of all transactions should be saved in second level Entities (Tables). (as you design correctly). Transaction types (e.g. Card, Cash, Bitcoin and etc.) have many different attributes. So putting all types in one entity, make some bad design traps like **Nullification**.

**Thirdly**: If you want to have a complete Accounting System to supports all accounting parts (like generating Balance Sheet), you should add many other entities.

**But** in this case, **you should hold Amount in Transaction**. Fining Amount in other tables is so difficult when you want to perform some queries based on overall Amount on Transaction.

Comment: If I add reversal into transaction table, then I need to a column in the transaction table so that I can reference to which transaction I reverse.

Comment: Absolutely, a Transaction can be added related to a previous Transaction.